# My CSS code isn't positioning my elements

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

```
.styled-select select {
    margin-top:200px;
    margin-left:300px;
    background: transparent;
    width: 268px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 34px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: block;
}
```

The HTML code is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="styled-select">
 <select name="selectPrimaryLocation">
    <option selected="selected">City Hall</option>
    <option>Flower Store</option>
 </select>
 </div>

 <div class="styled-select">
 <select name="selectSecondaryLocation">
    <option>Building 5</option>
    <option>Building 6</option>
 </select>
 </div>


</body>

</html>
```

The select box isn't being positioned in IE9. The browsers i am using for testing are IE6 to IE9

Comment: It is behaving correctly in IE8 for me

Comment: I see the listbox but it's not being positioned. I modify the margin-top and margin-left but I do not see the change. I also opened Developer Tools and changed the compatibility to IE7,8,9 but the position does not change. (The listbox does populate and the items do appear)

Comment: perhaps try floating or positioning the div `.styled-select`

Comment: what do you mean by floating or positioning?

Comment: `.styled-select{ float:left; }`

Comment: Do you have a link to the page that you are working on? Perhaps I can take a look at it and better address your issue

Comment: im working on it locally. the URL would be E:\web\index.html but I posted everything above. I want to learn how to position the elements so they are "next" to each other instead of on top of each other. I know I can make a table and put one in cell 0,0 then the other in cell 0,1. I was trying to avoid tables and use CSS.